# Read multiple images on a folder in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, file-io

I have a problem reading multiple images in Matlab from a folder. I want to read with their original name (with the command imread because are multiband). The names of the images are like '2001_01', '2001_02'. This is my code:

```
myPath= 'C:\images\'; %'
a=dir(fullfile(myPath,'*.tif'));
fileNames={a.name};
```

And then...

```
for k = 1:length(fileNames)
    filename = [fileNames(k).name];  
    I = imread(filename);
end
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know how to save and imread each one individually. Does somebody know how can I do it? Really thanks in advance,

Comment: Does it return the full file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it return the full file path? fileNames(k).name ? or just the actual file name? You might need to append myPath with filename taking care of slashes as well

```
fileName = strcat(myPath, fileName)
```

Then do the imread, make sure you have looked at the slashes once contactenated

Comment: better use `fullfile` than `strcat` in this context.

Comment: Thanks Wajih! Yes, it return the full file path and all the files.

Answer (score 6):

1. Regarding the first problem:

   > But it doesn't work...

   Just assign the output of `dir` directly into `fileNames` (without brackets):

   ```
   fileNames = dir(fullfile(myPath, '*.tif'));
   ```
2. Regarding the second problem:

   > ... I don't know how to save and `imread` each one individually.

   it seems that you need a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) to store all images in a single collection. First, define the cell array to have the right size:

   ```
   C = cell(length(fileNames), 1);
   ```

   and then store each image into a different cell:

   ```
   for k = 1:length(fileNames)
       filename = fileNames(k).name;
       C{k} = imread(filename);
   end
   ```

   To access any image in the cell array `C` later, use curly braces (`{}`). For instance, the second image is accessed as follows: `C{2}`.

Comment: Thanks Eitan for your quickly reply! It works! And it's possible that on the C{k} the list would appear the names of the files? The list show the "row x column x band".

Comment: You can make `C` a cell array with two columns, one for the stored images and one for the corresponding filenames. To do that, initialize the cell array like so: `C = cell(length(filenames), 2);` and in each iteration assign the cell values as following: `C{k, 1} = filename; C{k, 2} = imread(filename);`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
 fileNames={a.name};
```

Try

```
fileNames = arrayfun( @(x) fullfile( myPath, x.name ), a, 'UniformOutput', false );
```

Then, in the loop you can access the `k`-th file name as

```
I = imread( filenames{k} );
```

Comment: Thanks Shai, but I receive the following message: ??? Improper index matrix reference.

Comment: @user1578688 have you set `k`?